# Subtract Group Values in Data.Table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
data = data.frame(GROUP = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                  TYPE = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                  VALUE = c(1,6,9,3,5,0,2,3),
                  WANT = c(4,-6,-7,0))
```

I have 'data' as shown here. I want to subtract the VALUE for TYPE=0 from TYPE=1 for each GROUP and store in new variable WANT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data like yours, you can use:

```
data[, .(WANT = diff(VALUE)), by = GROUP][data, on = "GROUP"]
```

or even easier:

```
data[, WANT := diff(VALUE), by = GROUP]
```

Answer (score 1):

## tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  select(-WANT) %>%
  pivot_wider(GROUP, names_from = TYPE, values_from = VALUE) %>%
  mutate(GET = `1` - `0`) %>%
  pivot_longer(`0`:`1`, names_to = "TOPIC", values_to = "VALUE") %>%
  arrange(TOPIC, GROUP)
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   GROUP   GET TOPIC VALUE
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1     4 0         1
# 2     2    -6 0         6
# 3     3    -7 0         9
# 4     4     0 0         3
# 5     1     4 1         5
# 6     2    -6 1         0
# 7     3    -7 1         2
# 8     4     0 1         3
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
tmp1 <- dcast(as.data.table(data), GROUP ~ TYPE, value.var = "VALUE")[, GET := `1` - `0`]
melt(tmp1, id.vars = c("GROUP", "GET"), variable.name = "TOPIC", value.name = "VALUE")
#    GROUP GET TOPIC VALUE
# 1:     1   4     0     1
# 2:     2  -6     0     6
# 3:     3  -7     0     9
# 4:     4   0     0     3
# 5:     1   4     1     5
# 6:     2  -6     1     0
# 7:     3  -7     1     2
# 8:     4   0     1     3
```